# How to glue the system thanks to processes?

Tags: c, linux, process, fork

## Generalities and explanations about the functioning of my program

I wrote a program whose aim is to create processes until it can't do it anymore (id est : it must glue the OS and completely fill the processes table). However, when OS is glued, a message like "`fork` can't be done anymore" appears, and all the processes can be killed by the final user thanks to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

My program contains two important processes : the main one, which creates the second. The first is called "MAIN_P" in my code and the latter "P_ROOT". P_ROOT's aim is to `fork` until he can't do it anymore. When a `fork` error appears (id est : when my program has succeeded !), the final user can send a <kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd> signal to MAIN_P, which will kill P_ROOT and its children.

I precise that P_ROOT and its children have the same GPID (inheritance). But the latter is different than the MAIN_P's one, of course (`setsid` applied to P_ROOT).

---

## My problem

When I launch my program, it `fork` the first child, which `fork` its children until the OS is glued (ie. : until the processes table is completely filled). The only problem is that I can't <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> in my console to stop it... And of course, if I just exit the terminal, it doesn't kill all these processes (and others continue to be forked moreover).

**Thus, I don't recommend you to execute it...**

What is wrong with my code ?

---

## Source

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    pid_t pid_first_child = 0;
    if((pid_first_child = fork()) == -1) { // We `fork` the first child, which will always `fork` (more precisely : until the OS is glued, processes table completely filled)
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(pid_first_child == 0) { // BEGINNING OF <FirstChild>'S CODE

        pid_t pid_session_leader = 0;
        if((pid_session_leader = setsid()) == -1) { // FirstChild is its process group's leader
            perror("setsid");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if(setpriority(PRIO_PGRP, pid_session_leader, -10) == -1) { // The priority of FirstChild (which is the group's leader)
            perror("setpriority");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        unsigned children_counter = 0;
        pid_t pid_calculation_process = 0;
        while((pid_calculation_process = fork()) != -1) { // Now, FirstChild will `fork` until the limit ! When the limit is reached, -1 is returned : there isn't anymore `fork` and we exit the loop
            if(pid_calculation_process > 0) {
                children_counter++;
                fprintf(stdout, "%u\n", children_counter);
            } else { // BEGINNING OF <FirstChild's children>'s CODE (Why ? Consequently to the `while` and the `if` !)
                float j=1;
                while(1) { // Children can't die
                    int i = 0;
                    for(; i < 1000; i++) {
                        j /= 3;
                    }

                    usleep(1000);
                }
            } // END OF <FirstChild's children>'s CODE (FirstChild's children)
        }
        perror("fork"); // It's what we wanted ! This message will tell the user "OS is glued, program worked correctly"
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); // `EXIT_SUCCESS` ? Because we reached the limit !

    } // END OF <FirstChild>'S CODE
}
```

Comment: Try using `ulimit -u 50` to set your process limit before running the program. When you hit the limit you should get the error.

Comment: Hint: your // nota bene doesnt make much sense. When people are used that "p_" has a certain meaning then **dont** "override that meaning. Such initial comments will be overlooked sooner or later. Meaning: **never** put code in place that might *surprise* its readers!

Comment: @Barmar : I don't want to set the process limit in fact. I really want to completely fill the process table and to glue the OS. However, I want to be able, in the terminal, to CTRL + Z to kill all the processes and, thus, free the process table.

Comment: @GhostCat : thank you ! I completely changed my code (and discovered a new problem : I can't kill the processes with CTRL + Z) ; the new one is shorter. And I changed the names too.

Comment: Note : I wanted to write CTRL + C, not CTRL + Z (can't edit my comment sorry)

Answer (score 1):

Comments:

- To reach your fork() limit quickly, you have to make sure that each forked process doesn't consume too much resources.  Your forked processes are spinning in the for-loop and taking up too much resources.  If you remove the for-loop, you will hit your process limit more quickly since the processes will be blocked on the sleep() call instead of spinning.
- You don't need the wait loop to wait for the processes to complete after the fork() error.  That will happen automatically.

The updated source:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // This (first !) child, say "P_ROOT", will create its own children, which will glue the system (thus, MAIN_P is freed
    int p_root = fork();
    if(p_root == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // P_ROOT's PGID will be set to its PID (so we have : P_ROOT's PGID != MAIN_P's PGID)
    if (p_root == 0) {
       if(setpgid(p_root, p_root) == -1) {
          perror("setpgid");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       int p_root_number_of_created_children = 0;
       pid_t p_root_child = 0;
       while((p_root_child = fork()) != -1) { // P_ROOT forks until it can't do it anymore...
          if(p_root_child != 0) {
             p_root_number_of_created_children++;
          } else {
#ifdef CONSUME_RESOURCES
             int i = 0;
             while(i < 1000000000000000000) {
                i++;
             }
#endif
             sleep(6000);
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
          }
       }

       // NOW it's impossible to create new child processes
       perror("fork");
       fprintf(stdout, "\nImpossible to create more children. Their number is : %d\n", p_root_number_of_created_children);
       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    } else {
       printf("Waiting, top level, root = %d\n", p_root);
       wait(NULL); // MAIN_P waits for P_ROOT

       char cmd = 0;

       if(scanf("%c", &cmd) < 0) {
          perror("scanf");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       if(cmd == '\n' && kill(-p_root, SIGKILL) == -1) {
          perror("kill");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

Comment: With your (and my) code, I couldn't kill my processes with `\n` or CTRL + Z. I wrote another code, shorter. With this new one, I can't even do a CTRL + Z (it seems to be ignored by the terminal), and of course no process is killed. Moreover, the `fork` of new processes continue : I haven't any control on my OS, which I must restart each time I execute my program... (fortunately, I use VB). Could you take a look to my new shorter code please ? I commented it in details.

Comment: Note : I wanted to write CTRL + C, not CTRL + Z (can't edit my comment sorry)